Using PostgreSQL for Microsoft Orleans clustering and persistence storage is broken? column "silohost" does not exist
I created an Microsoft Orleans application using v7.2.7. I created the PostgreSQL tables using the links
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/orleans/host/configuration-guide/adonet-configuration.
However, the first issue is that the application fails with exception unless I manually insert a record:
insert into OrleansQuery(QueryKey, QueryText) values (
'CleanupDefunctSiloEntriesKey', 
'delete from OrleansMembershipTable
 where DeploymentId = @DeploymentId
   and @SiloHost = HostName
   and @SiloPort = Port
   and Status = @NonActiveStatus
   and IAmAliveTime < @IAmAliveTime;
 select ROW_COUNT();');

Then later, the application got exception when it does CleanupDefunctSiloEntriesKey:
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42703: column "silohost" does not exist
Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessageLong(Boolean async, DAtaRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNOtifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
POSITION: 79
at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ReadMessageLong(Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
at System. Runtime. CompilerServices. PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder'1.StateMachineBox'1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean async, CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean async, CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Orleans.Clustering. AdoNet.Storage.RelationalStorage.ExecuteReaderAsync[TResult] (DbCommand command, Func'4 selector, CommandBehavior commandBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in / /src/AdoNet/Shared/Storage/RelationalStorage.cs:line 251
at Orleans.Clustering. AdoNet. Storage. RelationalStorage. ExecuteAsync[TResult] (String query, Action'1 parameterProvider, Func'5 executor, Func 4 selector, CommandBehavior commandBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in / /src/AdoNet/Shared/Storage/RelationalStorage.cs:line 285
at Orleans. Clustering. AdoNet.Storage.RelationalStorage.ExecuteAsync(String query, Action'1 parameterProvider, CommandBehavior commandBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in / /src/AdoNet/Shared/Storage/RelationalStorage.cs:line 197
at Orleans. Runtime. MembershipService. AdoNetClusteringTable.CleanupDefunctSiloEntries(DateTimeOffset beforeDate) in //src/AdoNet/Orleans.Clustering. AdoNet/Messaging/AdoNetClusteringTable.cs:line 197
at Orleans. Runtime. MembershipService.MembershipTableCleanupAgent.CleanupDefunctSilos() in / /src/Orleans.Runtime/MembershipService/MembershipTableCleanupAgent.cs:line 71
Exception data:
Severity: ERROR
SqlState: 42703
MessageText: column "silohost" does not exist
Position: 79
File: parse_relation.c
Line: 3727
Routine: err ... [message truncated due to size]

BTW, I have the following setup:
private static void ConfigurePostgreSqlClustering(ISiloBuilder siloBuilder, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var config = configuration. GetSection("database").Get<DatabaseConfig>();
    ArgumentNullException. ThrowIfNull(config);
    var connectionString = $"Host={config. Server}; Database={config.Name}; Username={config.Username}; Password={config.Password}; Timeout=600;Command Timeout=600;";

    siloBuilder.UseAdoNetClustering(options =>
    {
        options.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        options.Invariant = "Npgsql";
    });
    siloBuilder.AddAdoNetGrainStorage(Constants.Orleans.GrainStorage, options =>
    {
        options. ConnectionString = connectionString;
        options. Invariant = "Npgsql";
    });
}

